# CSRF token error while requesting a json on post request

Tags: python, json, django

I am trying to render a json response on post request from django such that my view is

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import View

class TaskView(View):
    def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        return HttpResponse("hello",content_type="application/json")
    def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
         return HttpResponse("hello",content_type="application/json")
```

this has to return hello json response for both get as well as post request.

But i do a get request on this it is working . But if i do a post request then
i am getting the following error

```
Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
You are seeing this message because this HTTPS site requires a 'Referer header' to be sent by your Web browser, but none was sent. This header is required for security reasons, to ensure that your browser is not being hijacked by third parties.
If you have configured your browser to disable 'Referer' headers, please re-enable them, at least for this site, or for HTTPS connections, or for 'same-origin' requests.
Help
Reason given for failure:
    Referer checking failed - no Referer.

In general, this can occur when there is a genuine Cross Site Request Forgery, or when Django's CSRF mechanism has not been used correctly. For POST forms, you need to ensure:
Your browser is accepting cookies.
The view function uses RequestContext for the template, instead of Context.
In the template, there is a {% csrf_token %} template tag inside each POST form that targets an internal URL.
If you are not using CsrfViewMiddleware, then you must use csrf_protect on any views that use the csrf_token template tag, as well as those that accept the POST data.
You're seeing the help section of this page because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and only the initial error message will be displayed.
You can customize this page using the CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW setting.
```

My middleware class setting

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)
```

do i need to refactor any part of view to handle post request for json.

Comment: How are you sending the post request? Is it a form submit or over ajax etc? If you could edit in your template code it would be helpful

Comment: no i am using postman tool a chrome plugin

Comment: hi! have you solved this problem?

Comment: yup by using @csrf_exempt decorator..https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/_modules/django/views/decorators/csrf/#csrf_exempt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need implement explicit CSRF protection in your request:

```js
// using jQuery
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}

function sameOrigin(url) {
    // test that a given url is a same-origin URL
    // url could be relative or scheme relative or absolute
    var host = document.location.host; // host + port
    var protocol = document.location.protocol;
    var sr_origin = '//' + host;
    var origin = protocol + sr_origin;
    // Allow absolute or scheme relative URLs to same origin
    return (url == origin || url.slice(0, origin.length + 1) == origin + '/') ||
        (url == sr_origin || url.slice(0, sr_origin.length + 1) == sr_origin + '/') ||
    // or any other URL that isn't scheme relative or absolute i.e relative.
    !(/^(\/\/|http:|https:).*/.test(url));
}
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    }
});
```

See: [Cross Site Request Forgery protection](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using form submit or AJAX for `POST` call, you need to pass `{{csrf_token}}` along with form submission.

Comment: actually i made the request through a tool called postman a chrome plugin to test my api.